# Wordpress permalinks doesn't work on a subfolder installation

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

The site used to be on the main domain with the plugin "polylang", that created an extension "en" to my domain. I have disabled this plugin and installed a fresh wordpress on a sub folder called "en". 
I have kept the same URL's for SEO purposes.

Now when i press on any of the new URL's, If that URL used to exist on the old version of the site (with polylang) - it takes me to the old URL, without the /EN extension.

If i press on a new URL (that didn't exist on the polylang version) it takes me to a 404 page.

I have refreshed the "permalinks" under the page admin several times. made sure the .HTACCESS file is currect:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Disabled all plugins and moved the the default theme, but still this happens.

I took a look under my wp-config.php file and made sure i have this:

```
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.med-1.com/en' );
```

Also i cleared my browsing data.

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, I suspect you have links saved in your database as absolute urls - those will still point to the old site. There are a few options to try and do a smart search and replace in your database: https://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=wordpress%20search%20and%20replace%20url&oq=wordpress%20search%20and%20replace%20url&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5311j0j7 WARNING: backup your database before you do any search or replace or risk messing things up even more!

Comment: WordPress uses absolute urls. You would need to use a search and replace that includes serialized data. Better Search and Replace plugin does that. Make a back up of your database before you do this. Also, refresh your permalinks.

Comment: hi guys thank you for the help. i don't this this is the issue. when hovering one of the menu itemt, you can see it is directing to the currect URL. see screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/jmiWS , but then when pressing, it is actually going to a wrong URL, see: http://imgur.com/a/M680Z . you think this is DB related ? it looks like some kind of a strange 301

Comment: i got some progress done. i found that when i change the permalinks rules in the main folder site it changes also in the folder "en" wordpress, although they have totally different DB. how can this be ?